# Two php version on mac, can i fix it?

Tags: php, macos, configuration

I have a configuration problem about my php installation on my mac os x 10.9.2
If i do

```
php --version
```

on my terminal i get following output:

```
PHP 5.3.27 (cli) (built: Dec  4 2013 06:25:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

while if i try to check php version via phpinfo(), i get following

```
PHP Version 5.4.24
```

so i have two php different version installed, 5.3.27 for cli mode e 5.4.24 on server side.

Also if i try to change configuration in php.ini, at path that i see on phpinfo() response (/private/etc/php.ini), after restart apache, i don't see nothing change; so i think that php.ini maybe is in another place.

How can i do to fix my php installation to have only one php version?

Comment: You likely have a different php version in your `PATH`. Post the output of `which php`.

Comment: which php output is following:    /opt/local/bin/php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it 5.4 on the CLI also, try moving the one at `/opt/local/bin/php` out of `$PATH`.

Normally php lives at `/usr/bin/php`, so it should find that one when you move the one at `/opt/local/bin/php` out of `$PATH`. Maybe `echo $PATH` shows `/opt/local/bin/` before `/usr/bin/` for you?